# Text Column Validation: Numbers only, 5 numbers, a period, and 3 numbers

Tags: custom-list, column, column-validation

In my SharePoint list, I need a text column [ID] to validate as 5 numbers, a period, and then 3 numbers. Example:  "15202.123" and I need help.  :-)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(LEN([YourColumn])=9,IF(MID([YourColumn],6,1)=".",IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE((MID([YourColumn],1,5)))),ISNUMBER(VALUE((MID([YourColumn],7,3)))),FALSE),FALSE),FALSE)
```

First it validates if it's a 9 character string or not, then checks  if the 6th character is a dot (.), then it validates the first 5 and last 3 characters.

Of course, it might be possible to write in an easier way.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: UBK! Thank you!!! This is exactly what I was looking for. I REALLY appreciate your time and brilliance. Cheers!